# Autonomous Data Guard in Shared ADB infrastructure

Tags: oracle-autonomous-db

I have an ADB compartment in Shared ADB infrastructure with cross region standby. And I will have multiple ADB instances within the compartment. I understand that when i switchover from primary to secondary ADB instance,  the primary ADB instance will be locked and in replication mode.

So my question is - Is it just the ADB instance in primary region or the entire ADB compartment in primary that will be in replication mode? To be more specific the Autonomous Data guard is for the entire compartment or one per ADB instance?

Answer (score 0):

The standby is for a specific database. So, other databases in that compartment will not be impacted. Also see the documentation that shows you are enabling the standby for a single database, https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/autonomous-data-guard-enable.html#GUID-FE9962C8-B850-4ECF-B1E9-263864174305